# How Python can display data on Label by Access (SQL)?

Tags: python, sql, ms-access, select, tkinter

I want Python to display data from Access on Label. I tried to do smth like this but it doesn't work. There is no error but Label displays `pypyodbc.Cursor object at 0x05E02990`. What should I do? Thank you

```
from tkinter import *
import pypyodbc
import ctypes

#Create connection
con = pypyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};UID=admin;UserCommitSync=Yes;Threads=3;SafeTransactions=0;PageTimeout=5;MaxScanRows=8;MaxBufferSize=2048;FIL={MS Access};DriverId=25;DefaultDir=C:/Users/HP/Desktop/PITL;DBQ=C:/Users/HP/Desktop/PITL/PITL.mdb;')
cursor = con.cursor ()

form = Tk ()
form.title ("Main")
form.geometry ('400x400')

form2 = Tk ()
form2.title ("Main")
form2.geometry ('400x400')
form2.withdraw()

def Show():
    cursor.execute ("SELECT Law_ID FROM Laws WHERE Fine=1")
    a=cursor.execute
    for a in cursor:
        print ("Law ID where Fine is 1 is", a)
        Label(form2, text=cursor).pack() 
    form.withdraw()
    form2.deiconify()

Button(form, text = 'PUSH ME', command = Show).pack()

form.mainloop ()

con.commit ()
cursor.close ()
con.close ()
```

Comment: What happens when you replace `print ("Law ID where Fine is 1 is", a)` with `print ("Law ID where Fine is 1 is", list(a))`?

Comment: @Deadlock It doesn't change text in Label

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python cannot display data on Label twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48850828/python-cannot-display-data-on-label-twice)

Answer (score 2):

The error is because you are printing the value of cursor object which always be a location, in your case "0x05E02990". To get the value retrieved by the cursor you have to write:

```
variable_name = cursor.fetchall()
```

In your code:

```
def Show():
    cursor.execute ("SELECT Law_ID FROM Laws WHERE Fine=1")
    a=cursor.fetchall()
    ##print as you like
```

It will fetch all the data retrieved by cursor

Answer (score 0):

Try this one on your function

```py
def Show():

    cursor.execute ("SELECT Law_ID FROM Laws WHERE Fine=1")
    a=cursor.fetchall()

    for i in range(len(a)):
        print ("Law ID where Fine is 1 is", i)
        Label(form2, text=cursor).grid(row = i, column = 0)
```

Comment: Your solution still passes `cursor` object in `Label()`.